# Gradient Descent in Metric Learning for Kernel Regression (MLKR)

Tags: regression, gradient-descent, kernel-smoothing, gradient

I am currently studying the Metric Learning for Kernel Regression (MLKR) algorithm (http://proceedings.mlr.press/v2/weinberger07a/weinberger07a.pdf).

Let $\{(x_{1}, y_{1}), ..., (x_{N}, y_{N})\}$ denotes the training set. The authors of this paper propose to optimize a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ by minimizing the leave-one-out error:
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{A}) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \big( y_{i} - \hat{y_{i}}(\mathbf{A}) \big)^{2}, 
$$
$$
\hat{y_{i}}(\mathbf{A}) = \frac{\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N} k_{ij}(\mathbf{A})y_{j} }{\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N} k_{ij}(\mathbf{A})}
$$
where $k_{ij}(\mathbf{A})$ is the Gaussian kernel:
$
k_{ij}(\mathbf{A}) = e^{-x_{ij}^{\mathbf{T}}\mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{T}}\mathbf{A}x_{ij}}
$
and $x_{ij} = x_{i} - x_{j}$.

They state that the gradient of the loss function with respect to $\mathbf{A}$ is (Eq. 8):
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \mathbf{A}}(\mathbf{A}) = 4\mathbf{A}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \big( \hat{y_{i}}(\mathbf{A}) - y_{i}\big) \sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N}\big( \hat{y_{j}}(\mathbf{A}) - y_{j}\big)k_{ij}(\mathbf{A})x_{ij}x_{ij}^{\mathbf{T}}.
$$
I can't figure out how they get this expression.

My attempt:
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \mathbf{A}}(\mathbf{A}) = 2 \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \big( \hat{y_{i}}(\mathbf{A}) - y_{i}\big)\frac{\partial \hat{y_{i}}(\mathbf{A})}{\partial \mathbf{A}}(\mathbf{A})
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \hat{y_{i}}(\mathbf{A})}{\partial \mathbf{A}}(\mathbf{A}) &= \frac{\Big(\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N} \frac{\partial k_{ij}}{\partial \mathbf{A}}(\mathbf{A})y_{j}  \Big)\Big(\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N} k_{ij}(\mathbf{A}) \Big)-\Big(\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N} k_{ij}(\mathbf{A})y_{j}  \Big)\Big(\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N} \frac{\partial k_{ij}}{\partial \mathbf{A}}(\mathbf{A}) \Big)}{\Big(\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N} k_{ij}(\mathbf{A}) \Big)^{2}} \\
&= \frac{\Big(\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N} \frac{\partial k_{ij}}{\partial \mathbf{A}}(\mathbf{A})y_{j}  \Big)- \hat{y_{i}}(\mathbf{A})\Big(\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N} \frac{\partial k_{ij}}{\partial \mathbf{A}}(\mathbf{A}) \Big)}{\Big(\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N} k_{ij}(\mathbf{A}) \Big)} \\
&=
\frac{\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N} \big(y_{j}-\hat{y_{i}}(\mathbf{A}) \big)\frac{\partial k_{ij}}{\partial \mathbf{A}}}{\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N} k_{ij}(\mathbf{A})} =2\mathbf{A} \frac{\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N} \big(y_{j}-\hat{y_{i}}(\mathbf{A})\big)k_{ij}(\mathbf{A})x_{ij}x_{ij}^{\mathbf{T}} }{\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N} k_{ij}(\mathbf{A})}
\end{align*}
Hence, I have
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \mathbf{A}}(\mathbf{A}) = 4\mathbf{A} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \big( \hat{y_{i}}(\mathbf{A}) - y_{i}\big)\frac{\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N} \big(y_{j}-\hat{y_{i}}(\mathbf{A})\big)k_{ij}(\mathbf{A})x_{ij}x_{ij}^{\mathbf{T}} }{\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{N} k_{ij}(\mathbf{A})}
$$

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your derivation is correct. Check page 12 of this book. Their loss function is essentially the same and they arrive at your result. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-540-88906-9.pdf